# Automatically change keyword to uppercase in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use a programming language whose keywords are all uppercase (`RETURN`, `IF`, `ELSE`, `PRINT`).
I find it very tedious to have the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key held down while typing those.

In Vim I have created abbreviations for all keywords which I find is a decent solution.

`iab <silent> <buffer> if <C-R>=ToUpper('if')<CR>`

Now I was wondering whether there is any similar way to accomplish this in VSCode. I don't want have to use snippets/templates for every single keyword.

Comment: Does your programming language have Intellisense (suggestions) as you type? If so, then you should just be able to write `else`, have the language tools suggest `ELSE`, and then hit return to accept the current selection to insert `ELSE`

Comment: @MattBierner, unfortunately it does not. All it has is syntax highlighting.